# Process crashed with: TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, http, post, callback, request

I am trying to call this function that has an HTTP post request so that I can get the body in different parts of the bigger script

Below is the code:

```
var request = require('request')
var myJSON = require("JSON");

function getJSON ( input, callback){
var all = {
  'documents': [
    {
      'id': '1',
      // Change this text to test
      'text': 'not helpful' 
    }
  ]
};
request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' :'0df563b09d8b42b095dd32158e4afd13',
      'Host' : 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com'
    },
    uri: 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment',
      json: true,

    body: all,
    method: 'POST'
  }, function (error, response, body) {

         if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback(error || {statusCode: response.statusCode});
    }
    else
    callback(body);  
    return callback;
  });
}

 body = getJSON("test");
```

Comment: ----------------------
    
    This is the error im getting:
    
    Process crashed with: TypeError: callback is not a function
        at Request._callback (evalmachine.<anonymous>:30:5)

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, when you called your function getJSON, you did not provide a callback parameter.

```
body = getJSON("test"); // <--- Missing parameter
```

Meaning, getJSON("test") is missing a callback parameter.
I.E. 
`getJSON("test", function(){console.log("Do something")});`

This probably leads to the callback parameter to be undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much!! But now that I want to pass the body of the request to the full script how do I do it?
instead of var answer = getJSON("test", function(){console.log("Do something")}); I want to store the body of the response in answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Reina Baba - What you wanted to do cannot be done in your code. You are only getting the body of the response as part of the promise returned from making the POST request. You cannot pass the request body when calling the function getJSON since you do not have it yet. I would break apart the method to return the body of the response and then run any logic you need on it. **If my answer helped you, consider marking it as an answer.**